# Do you know a name and expression of this function of Lehmer?

Tags: number-theory, terminology, analytic-number-theory

In the paper "A new calculus of numerical functions." (D.H. Lehmer, 1931) Lehmer defines a function d as follows.

The function d(i,n) may be defined as follows: d(i,n)=0, if i is not a divisor of n. Otherwise d(i,n) is the largest divisor d of i for which n/d is prime to d.

I would like to know if, later, this function was named in anyway. Do you know an equivalent expression of this function in more generally known arithmetical functions?

UPDATE:

There is a theorem that converts an LCM sum to a Divisor sum.

$$\sum_{[ab]=n}f(a)=\sum_{\delta/n}f(\delta)\tau(d(\delta,n))$$

where $\tau$ is the common divisor count function, [ab] are all 2-tuples with LCM[a,b]=n, d the function as mentioned above.

Comment: There is a book Divisors by Hall and Tenenbaum where a lot of stuff like the above is studied - not sure if it has exactly that but if you have access to a copy of the book, it may worth looking through as it deals with the fine structure of divisors https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/divisors/448D6E9200B5B935EF41C081BA6DEB7A

Comment: What is this function is useful for ?

Comment: Solving LCM ( x,m ) = n

Comment: @Conrad I have that book, it is about sieves mostly. I came across the function in an attempt solving an exercise in McCarthy's Introduction to Arithmetical Functions.

Comment: The number $d$ itself, with the property that $(d,n/d)=1$, is called a _primary divisor_ of $n$. I don't know of any name for this specific function involving primary divisors.

Comment: For the time being I have implemented the function in my MMa package under the name nLehmerD; Lehmer Divisor or Lehmer's Divisor ( waiting for an official name ).

Comment: Is your implementation a brute-force implementation requiring knowledge of the factors/divisors of $i$? If so, I can post a more optimal implementation.

Comment: This is my implementation in MMa / Wolfram Language

nLehmerD[i_, n_] := 0 /; Not[Divisible[n, i]]
nLehmerD[i_, n_] := 1 /; i == 1
nLehmerD[i_, n_] := Apply[Times, Map[#[[1]]^#[[2, 1]] &, Select[Map[{#, IntegerExponent[{i, n}, #]} &, 
      FactorInteger[GCD[i, n]][[All, 1]]], #[[2, 1]] == #[[2, 2]] &]]] /; Divisible[n, i]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on your implementation. I'll post my implementation as an answer since I believe it's a bit easier to read and understand in that format.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it soon.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the function $d(i,n)$ can be computed rather efficiently for large magnitudes of $i$ and $n$ without knowing the factors/divisors of $i$ or $n$ as follows. The formulas below are expressed in the Wolfram language and were implemented and tested in Mathematica. Note the $f(i,n)$ function defined in formula (2) below returns the final value of the local variable $y$.

---

**(1)** $\ d(\text{i$\_$},\text{n$\_$})\text{:=}\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 f(i,n) & i|n \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\right.$

**(2)** $ f(\text{i$\_$},\text{n$\_$})\text{:=}\text{Module}\left[\left\{y=i,g=\gcd \left(\frac{n}{i},i\right)\right\},\text{While}\left[g\neq 1,y=\frac{y}{g};g=\gcd \left(\frac{n}{y},y\right)\right];y\right]$

---

The $f(i,n)$ function defined in formula (2) above can also be implemented recursively as follows.

---

**(3)** $\ f(\text{i$\_$},\text{n$\_$})\text{:=}\text{Module}\left[\left\{g=\gcd \left(\frac{n}{i},i\right)\right\},
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 f\left(\frac{i}{g},n\right) & g\neq 1 \\
 i & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\right.
\right]$

---

Here's a conjectured relationship between the function $d(i,n)$ and [OEIS Entry A165430: Table T(n,m) read by rows: the greatest common unitary divisor of n and m, n>=1, 1<=m<=n.](https://oeis.org/A165430)

---

**(4)** $\quad d(i,n)\ne 0\implies d(i,n)=T(i,n)$